# Plotly's layout.geo.fitbounds attribute not working as expected

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm decoding polylines to map routes using Plotly Express/Dash. I'm able to successfully plot routes and display the maps in Dash, but I'm unable to get the `layout.geo.fitbounds` attribute to work as described in the documentation:

> The `layout.geo.fitbounds` attribute can be set to `locations` to
> automatically set the center and latitude and longitude range
> according to the data being plotted.

Example code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import dash_core_components as dcc

fig = px.line_geo(lat=[0,15,20,35], lon=[5,10,25,30])
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations")

dcc.Graph(figure=fig)
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure=fig)
])
app.run_server()
```

This results in the same zoom level as when I don't pass it a `fitbounds` parameter:
[image: Sample data mapped]

Do I need to be doing some formatting on the Dash end to make auto-zoom work?

Any advice greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if I fully understand what you are trying to do, but if you put a range in the code for drawing a line as shown below, won't it always zoom automatically even if the latitude and longitude change? `fig = px.line_geo(lat=[0,15,20,35], lon=[5,10,25,30],fitbounds="locations")`

Comment: @r-beginners My understanding from the documentation is setting `fitbounds="locations"` will cause it to zoom automatically based on the latitude & longitude lists passed to it, but when I try the code like you've written it results in a zoomed out map like the image above.